# Is your question already answered or simply lost in samsara stream here?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer, unanswered-questions, bounty

It could be easy that your question got lost and your are still not satisfied. Assuming that many questions are not marked as solved because the questioner simply forgot or has lost the interest on his question does not make it for sure to work off all questions.

So that your question does not become a victim of such assuming, you may have the possibility to answere here and post a link to it, even if it is not your question but you would desire a satisfactory answer.

Others would have the possibility to make maybe useful *[Dana](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/tags/dana/info)* (generosity) by giving it a start [bounty](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) (meaning giving away some of their reputations to benefit the location of your question) or by simply become aware of your wish and doing direct service (*Veyyāvaca*).

*Note: As it has become a meta topic, its also of use for questions of how things are done, living with the system.*

Answer (score 2):

Unanswered questions can be improved with edits, if your question has a similar question that was never closed, you can edit it and make the question easier to read, fix grammar and formatting etc.

This moves the question "Up the stack"

If you do not see a question that matches your question you should just ask your question.  Sometimes someone else will show a possible duplicate and if the pointed at duplicate answers your original question then you can close the question. If it does not, you can edit your question so that it is more clear as to why the pointed at question is not a duplicate.

Comment: It's good to have a meta answer here. Maybe your info would be good included in the question as info of normal ways when you see this as reason why your question got lost.